# Capture the text of a LABEL to be used in QUERY

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have reorganized everything then.

I want to capture the text that is contained in a label I have in a form in order 
to be used as the input for the `WHERE` criteria.

The query is the next called *qry_A*:

```sql
SELECT
tbl_R.ID_R,
tbl_C.Cuenta, 
tbl_C.Nombre, 
IIf(tbl_RD.Deb Is Null,0,tbl_RD.Deb) AS Deb, 
IIf(tbl_RD.Cre Is Null,0,tbl_RD.Cre) AS Cre, 
tbl_R.NIT, 
tbl_R.Fecha, 
tbl_R.Com, 
tbl_F.ID_F, 
tbl_R.ID_U

FROM 
(tbl_F INNER JOIN tbl_R ON tbl_F.ID_F = tbl_R.Fideicomiso) 
INNER JOIN (tbl_C RIGHT JOIN tbl_RD ON tbl_C.Cuenta = tbl_RD.Cuenta) ON tbl_R.ID_R = tbl_RD.ID_R

WHERE ((tbl_R.ID_U)=[Forms]![frm_qry_A]![lbl_Usuario]);
```

I've checked the name of the label and the name of the form. Not sure if this is possible to do with a label, I've checked and tried with a Text Field in the form and it works, I mean, if I capture the text of a  Text Field of another form that I have it goes, this is the line added to the query in order to illustrate what I did:

```sql
WHERE ((tbl_R.ID_U)=[Forms]![frm_B]![txt_Usuario]);
```

With that I capture the criteria or text declared in the Form called *form_B* as this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.lbl_Usuario.Caption = LCase(UsuarioLogeado)
    Me.txt_Usuario = UsuarioLogeado
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the input window?

Comment: As soon as I can, what can tell us that?

Comment: I wanted to see the message on the input window.  It may show me how to fix your issue.

Comment: post your `qry_A` query, may be there is some error in its SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label's `Caption` property contains the text which the label displays.  So reference `Caption` explicitly when you reference the label in the SQL statement.

```sql
WHERE tbl_R.ID_U=[Forms]![frm_B]![lbl_Usuario].Caption
```

Comment: I've had tried the `Caption` property and with no result. My main problem here was that I called that Label from the query form (_frm_qry_A_) and that give me no results, so what I did is to call that Label, which has the same name, from the other form (_frm_B_)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to type `Parameters` collection name:

```
'Associate parameter
tomarConsulta.Parameters!capturarUsuario = txt_Usuario
```

or better:

```
'Associate parameter
tomarConsulta.Parameters("capturarUsuario").Value = txt_Usuario
```

Comment: Thanks, I've included this and still I have the same result